# How do i clear the server-side datatables table rows in client-side

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, datatables, server-side

I have tried to clear the server-side datatables on the client side using
`table.fnClearTable();`
i have as well used `table.clear().draw();` but i havent had any success with it any one who can help me out that has used server-side datatables.
I want to as well filter the table content by date that appears in one of the columns.

I'll be glad with your help.

Comment: The version is _1.9+_

Comment: What about this one :
https://jsfiddle.net/z7xov3eo/46/

Comment: Okay its still not working but maybe this can give you an idea of what am trying to achive. I have filters **select tags in html** that i want to select then it filters the json that has already loaded in server-side datatables.

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense - it sounds like you want to load the table with server-side data, and then filter as though it was client-side. Is that correct?

Comment: what could be the best option please if you can help me out here... the table has serverside data but i want when i send a post value to the file it returns filtered content to the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refresh the table using

```
$('#table_id').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

function which will dynamically refresh.